# Building your own MenuBar

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is it possible to create its own component (Menu) that will be displayed on each screen?

Something like a ready Tab Bar

How it works:

- the bar is transparent
- each screen occupies the full height of the screen (it is also visible under the bar)

[image]

Comment: you can use customtab bar https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbar